# guardar formatos mp3 en BD y reproducirlos es un Streaming

Tags: php, html5, base-de-datos, base64, stream

Buen día, me encuentro desarrollando un proyecto tipo radio en la web, donde lo común que yo he hecho es dividir  el `index` de la web con un `frame` agrego un `Streaming` conectado con `ZaraRadio`. sin embargo para hacerlo así tengo que tener todas las canciones en formato `.mp3` en el servidor o en algún sitio. lo que quiero es lograr esto desde la base de datos y ahorrarme el tener que tener tanta data en un ordenador mi pregunta es :

existe alguna manera de hacerlo? quizá un `script` para el reproductor?

muchas gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Te aconsejaría no hacer eso. Es una conocida mala práctica de desarrollo. El sistema de archivos está para bregar con archivos y las base de datos están para bregar con datos.

Comment: pero creo que el mantenimiento seria un poco mas fácil. aunque se que trae sus desventajas me gustaría intentarlo

Answer (score 2):

lo que puedes hacer, es colocar los el fichero .mp3 en el servidor en un directorio como lo tienes. En la base de datos solo colocas el nombre del fichero.

Comment: no querrás decir la ruta

Comment: Puede ser la ruta si es mas de un directorio o el nombre del archivo si todo es un solo directorio

Comment: seria el mismo procedimiento que explique en la preguntano pero por ejemplo el `Streaming` que he usado no es así sino que se conecta en `ZaraRadio`  directamente, por eso pregunte por un `script` asi, como se guarda en `Base64` una imagen, pero en vez de imagen `.mp3` pero mi problema no seria codificarlo, sino decodificarlo y hacer que suene